# wi-fi adapter driver NW602 AC600

Tags: 20.04, adapter

I had an issure with the drivers for the "NW602 AC600" wifi adapter

lsusb gave this as an output:
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall build-essential bc dkms git
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8821cu-20210118.git
cd 8821cu-20210118
sudo ./install-driver.sh
sudo modprobe 8821cu
```

You should be all set.